# Firestore - configure security in parent collection and use in child without additional fetch

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Structure of Firestore:

```
Parent (root): /projects/$(projectId)
Child (sub-col.): /projects/$(projectId)/someItems/${someItemId}
```

I started with these security rules:

```
match /projects/{projectId} {

  allow read: if isInCurrentProject(100);
  allow write: if isInCurrentProject(10);

  match /someItems/{someItemId} {
    allow read: if isInProject(projectId, 30)
    allow write: if isInProject(projectId, 20)
  }
}
```

First function isInCurrentProject for parent is fine, no fetch required:

```
function isInCurrentProject(minRole) {
    return resource.data.roles[request.auth.uid] <= minRole;
}
```

Currently this is my function isInProject:

```
function isInProject(projectId, minRole) {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects/$(projectId)).data.roles[request.auth.uid] <= minRole;
}
```

This seems to work, but my question is if there is any way how could I receive `resource.data` of parent inside child in a way that I don't have to do additional fetch (since that's counted as additional database request). Something like `resource.parent.data.roles...`
If not, is this feature at least on roadmap?

Since I want to secure each read and write in the child, this seems like a lot of database fetching.

Or is there at least some inheritance option where I can define that first you need to be able to access parent and if not, you can't access children at all? Because right now if I will make the parent more strict (I can't access it with certain account, not enough permission level) I still can access children (when I know the ID of the parent)

Sources:

[Role based access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access)

[Rules conditions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions)